# Disable auto {} insertion for React props in PyCharm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pycharm, webstorm, jsx

When I type props into my React component in PyCharm, it automatically inserts a pair of curly braces. Like so (cursor position is `|`):

```
<MyComp className=|
```

Becomes:

```
<MyComp className={|}
```

I've searched through the settings but didn't find a related setting to disable it. Does it exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable braces auto-insertion by turning off
`"Add quotes for attribute value on typing '=' and attribute completion"`
in `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys`

But this will disable quotes auto-insertion for HTML too.